# How to disable file upload in struts 2?

Tags: java, file-upload, jboss, struts2, apache-commons-fileupload

My we application is facing constant intrusions. It is hosted in windows server. I have posted my issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653568/jboss-struts-2-application-intrusions) before.

I have also update all the jars, but with no results.
Now what I found is that some unwanted files are upload uploaded in the server, which takes 100% CPU or making unknown activities to the server.

I guess they are uploaded from my web application of struts2. Jboss console is provided in [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653568/jboss-struts-2-application-intrusions) here. Now my question is if there is any way to  stop uploading files via struts2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried some thing like this in your web.xml file :           
  <multipart-config>
      <max-file-size>0</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>0</max-request-size>
    </multipart-config> I suppose your app don't need any uplaod at all.

Comment: Have you updated S2? Which version you are using?

Comment: It is now 2.3.32 from the month of April '2017.

Comment: You should be fine with S2. You can upgrade to `2.3.34` to avoid others vulnerabilities. Windows server? You can't be sure that is a S2 issue.

Comment: Yes, windows 2008 R2 server. Let me see after upgrading S2 to 2.3.34